# JAXB2 Maven plugin Getter Customization

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jaxb2, xjc

I have a xsd file, and i want to generate Class using maven jaxb2 plugin and customize the getter code for all the complexType.

Instead of

```
public Object getObject() {
   return obj;
}
```

I need

```
public Object getObject() {
    if(obj == null)
        obj = new Object();
    return obj;
}
```

How i can do that, is there an options like -XSetter who can natively do that?

I seen that we can write our own xjc plugin, maybe a way to do it...

Regards

Comment: Can you be more accurate which plugin you exactly using? Which version are you using? This one http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/index.html ?

Comment: yes, this one in 1.5 version by i can use another, it's not a matter.